# How can I get feeds to show up on front page or other designated sections of my news site?

Tags: feeds

How can I get feeds to show up on front page or other designated sections of my news site?

I have a DFrupal 8 site using the News theme. I don't know how to set up the RSS feeds to show on the front page as teasers for the section where the feed would normally reside.